# MVC 4 Bootstrap - Icon Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, font-awesome

I have an issue where icons are not displaying when publishing remotely. If I run the project within Visual Studio 2010 via `http://localhost:62299/` I see everything perfectly in Firefox, but if I use the same browser to view the remote website, the icons do not show. Getting varied results across verions of IE too.

I have ensured the full /Contents and /Scripts folders have been copied across in their entirety to ensure no files have been omitted. But despite this, icons will still not show.

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryold").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/Compatibility/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryuiold").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/Compatibility/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ie9").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/html5shiv.js",
                        "~/Scripts/respond.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/freelanceold").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.easing.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/classie.js",
                        "~/Scripts/freelancer.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/freelance").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.easing.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/classie.js",
                        "~/Scripts/cbpAnimatedHeader.js",
                        "~/Scripts/freelancer.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                        "~/Content/Site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/font-awesome").Include(
                        "~/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

**_layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    </head>

    <body id="page-top">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        @RenderBody()
        <footer class="text-center">
            <div class="footer-below">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            Copyright &copy; 2014 - MySite
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <div class="scroll-top page-scroll visible-xs visble-sm">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#page-top">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryold")
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        <!--<![endif]-->
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/freelance")

        <!-- IE8 support for HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9 !IE]>
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ie9")
        <![endif]-->    

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be be much appreciated  :-)

Comment: which icons are not displaying, i suspect their url is wrong

Comment: I agree with @EhsanSajjad, could your paths to the icons be relative to the wrong place? Try using developer console in Chrome for example and see if you are getting any 404 errors when trying to load those assets.

Comment: I will have a look using the developer console, but if I'm publishing the project via Visual Studio 2010, how can localhost be different to the remote?

Comment: Firstly you may be publishing to a subdirectory, eg your site runs on `www.domain.com/mysite` and the icons are trying to come from `/icons/foo.png' which is outside the scope of your project. Secondly, in release mode bundling optimises your CSS and JS files.

Comment: This is what I've just got from the developer console `Request URL: http://WebApplication1/Content/font-awesome?v=RQz58PBPiAX9UQCybbfMPkfO33wv39gGmQRFOVCaIi41 Request Method: GET
Status Code: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` `Request URL: http://WebApplication1/Content/font-awesome/?v=RQz58PBPiAX9UQCybbfMPkfO33wv39gGmQRFOVCaIi41
Request Method: GET Status Code: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`

Comment: And yes I am publishing to a subfolder inetpub\WebApplication1

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with a set of css files, where the request to the combined style url would result in a 301, then the final destination resulted in a 403 (forbidden).  It's because your style bundle url of **"~/Content/font-awesome"** matches an actual folder path.  I think the virtual path resolution is matching it to an actual physical folder location first, and if that fails, then it matches to a virtual bundle url if possible.  If you change it to what I have below and update your view to match, you should be fine:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/font-awesome-bundle").Include(
                        "~/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"));
```

---

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome-bundle")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with a project at work. What is happening is that some of the font-awesome files weren't included in the publish.

The .eot, .tff, and .woff were not included for me. I had to click on the files, and change the Build Action from "None" to "Content". At that point, they would output correctly.

For the record, that was in Visual Studio 2010, but in 2013, it appears that they are set to "Content" correctly.

Comment: I copied the entire source folder /Contents to the internal IIS server to ensure no files were missing, I have just been informed that our internal IIS server prevents external access to now need to localise `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400`

Comment: Ugh, that sucks. Sorry my answer couldn't help, but I hope you don't mind if I leave it up for someone else, just in case.

Comment: No worries, thank you for taking the time out, I actually resolved this myself in another post. If its of any interest, please see `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576264/mvc-4-google-fonts-intranet` :-)

Comment: Ah, glad to see you got it sorted out. The `font-awesome` paths in your console logs is what lead me down my path. One other thing about getting your stylesheets from Google remotely: If you're going to be running your site under `https`, remove the protocol from your URL. So it would just be `//fonts.googleapis.com/...` because even setting it as `https` won't get it to work from my company's observation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with font awesome below listed is my current bundle value and this solved the issue with additional references from Font-awesome.css file

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Framework/libs/vendor/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome").Include( "~/Framework/libs/vendor/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css"));

when the path is relative the to the actual font-awesome css file the relative path to the eot,tff and woff files will also become correct.