# MVC 4 Google Fonts - Intranet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a MVC4 4 Bootstrap project which renders perfectly well locally via Visual Studio 2010 but when I publish to the internal IIS used for our Intranet I cannot access the resource `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400` so could somebody explain how I localise this remote resource so that IIS references it locally.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To localise the Google Fonts I added the address `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400` in to my browser address bar which returns a css file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/montserrat/v4/zhcz-_WihjSQC0oHJ9TCYFQlYEbsez9cZjKsNMjLOwM.eot);
  src: local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/montserrat/v4/zhcz-_WihjSQC0oHJ9TCYFQlYEbsez9cZjKsNMjLOwM.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/montserrat/v4/zhcz-_WihjSQC0oHJ9TCYBsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format('woff');
}
```

I then added each url from the above css into my address bar which downloaded the associated .eot and .woff files. I simply renamed the downloaded files with a more logical name and copied the files into the /Content/fonts directory.

I then included the following into my boostrap.css file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(fonts/montserrat-400.eot);
  src: local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(fonts/montserrat-400.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(fonts/montserrat-400.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Hey presto, all fonts render correctly on an internal IIS server.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that google uses browser sniffing to detect your browser and then renders you the correct stylesheet based on the type of font it thinks your browser will prefer. For instance, if you stick that link in an old IOS device it will give you a different stylesheet, put it in an IE8 browser and yet another stylesheet will appear using different fonts. This is not a good answer. Do your homework on the google API, anyone on your network may have an old browser, an IOS device of new or old an android maybe, each need the correct stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in head tag

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: It is, but this project is running on our intranet IIS server and external access is denied so I cant access the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with font awesome below listed is my current bundle value and this solved the issue with additional references from Font-Awesome.css file

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Framework/libs/vendor/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome").Include(
            "~/Framework/libs/vendor/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css"));
```

when the path is relative the to the actual font-awesome css file the relative path to the  eot,tff and woff files will also become correct.