# How to use Google Fonts with .NET MVC 5?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fonts

I am trying to use Google Fonts in my .NET website. This is proving incredibly difficult and not as simple as I expected.

In my CSS I am of course adding the correct google style. But it is not rendering when launching the website.

I have tried using Googles Nugget package, as well as just adding the css url like you are supposed to in the header.

I tried researching this, but found almost zero questions. So this is probably something super simple that my tired programming brain can't think of.

Any help?

Comment: Could you please update your question with code samples showing how you're embedding the font and how you use the font?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/24576264/3222478

Answer (score 0):

I know that everybody have already got answer to this question from chat-GPT but I want to give my answer.

First of all, add your font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Itim';
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Itim&display=swap');
}
```

Then set it for your body and html:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Itim', sans-serif;
}
```

Just be cariful with this margin: 0;
Your web-page can behaving very strangely  with or without it.